# PHP, is possible to save html generated dynamically in a session variable?

Tags: php, session

I was wondering...

I have this html for example generated dynamically with php:

```
<div>
 <ul>
  <li>Some content</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

This content will change always depend of the user input. So my question.. is possible to save the html generated after render the page in a `$_SESSION` variable and then return it in another page?

The only idea I have is:

```
//after query the sql

$_SESSION['html'][] = 'html content';
echo 'html content';
```

so after render all the page I will have all my html stored in the $_SESSION['html'] variable... but doesn't look good :S

Comment: Yeah, nothing wrong with doing that. Is that the extent of the question?

Comment: well while I write the question I had the idea and the maybe I can implode the variable and get the html together... but in that way I need to copy each echo to the variable $_SESSION['html']... and I have like 50 :S

Comment: What about resource consuming? If there are multiple users that stores the html data and if html data is rather big?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<div>
 <ul>
  <li>Some content</li>
<?php echo "<li>Some more content</li>"; ?>
 </ul>
</div>
<?php
$_SESSION['html'][] = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_flush();   // or ob_end_clean();
```

The "ob" functions are for output buffering.  They will capture in a buffer all output from echo statements or outside `<?php ?>` tags.  After saving what's in the buffer with `ob_get_contents`, you can then send what's in the buffer with `ob_end_flush` or discard it with `ob_end_clean`.

Comment: yes, this is!! just delete the $ at the begging of the ob_end_flush();

Comment: D-oh!  "$" removed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong to do that. Just change this

```
$_SESSION['html'][] = 'html content';
```

To

```
$_SESSION['html'] = 'html content';
```

and when you want to append something more do like this:

```
$_SESSION['html'] .= 'html content';
```

Comment: no no, because the html is output in a lot of different echo and to big... I need to store 100 lines and maybe more

Comment: See the updated answer, you can append more anytime later.

Comment: But yes, there is nothing wrong, if you want to put those into an array and join together when you are using. Just be sure you are doing it properly.